# Preferred way to access props in Vue Single File Component

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

Suppose I have a prop named `message` which I want to access from the script section of a .vue file.
I know that it can be accessed using `this.$props.message` and `this.message` from the `data` function.

Which is the preferred way to access props from different [lifecycle hooks](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Options-Lifecycle-Hooks) (created, mounted, etc), and from [computed getters](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html), and [methods](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-Caching-vs-Methods)?

Comment: typical is `this.message`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Component properties as well as passed in props should always be referenced to by `this.propName`, because you shouldn't assign a component property with the same name as a passed in prop. In this case Vue will respond with an error.

Answer (score 0):

As **Aer0** said, they shouldn't have the same names:

```
props: ['propMessage'],

data() {
   return {
      message: ''
   };
},

created() {
    console.log(this.propMessage);
    console.log(this.message);
}
```